# Getting different address within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to show the miles between an origin and destination. Problem is I'm having trouble writing the query to properly show the destination address. There is only one location table which holds the address of both origin and destination. What am I doing wrong here?

I thought I would get the proper address for the destination and/or location but it's not working.

```
select  dist.DistanceId,
        dist.OriginLocationId,
        l.Address,
        dist.DestinationLocationId,
        l.Address,
        dist.DistanceInMiles        
from DistanceMatrixFromGoogleMapsApi as dist
join locations as l
on l.id = dist.OriginLocationId or l.id = dist.DestinationLocationId
    where OriginLocationId in (30506,53097,30362,30505,30377,30378,30594,30379,30514,30518,30517,55055,30360,30515,30516,30616,30512,30511,30510,30513,30381,49129)
        and DestinationLocationId in (53097,30362,30505,30377,30378,30594,30379,30514,30518,30517,55055,30360,30515,30516,30616,30512,30511,30510,30513,30381,49129,34690)
```

[These are the results I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZHPJ.png)

Comment: MySQL doesn't use T-SQL, so why tag it? T-SQL (Transact-SQL) is the dialect used by SQL Server and Sybase. What (R)DBMS are you really using?

Comment: I couldn't think of anything else to tag. I'm using MS SQL Server and T-SQL

Comment: Then you should be tagging SQL Server, not MySQL. *"I couldn't think of anything else to tag"* it's **up to** 5 tags, not *must have* 5 tags. I assume that the other 2 tags were (effectively) tag spam too, as there are no subqueries in the above, so I've removed those as well.

Comment: Avoid explaining things in text or images, better show sample input and expected outcome as tables. Linking off to other websites is very bad, no one can be sure that's no spam.

Comment: You need 2 joins here, not 1; one for the origin one for the destination.

Comment: Ok, I'll add another join. @Jonas, I will going forward. Sorry about that ...

Comment: I seem to get the same result when added a destination join. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Larnu -

```
SELECT
    dist.DistanceId,
    dist.OriginLocationId,
    orig.Address,
    dist.DestinationLocationId,
    dest.Address,
    dist.DistanceInMiles        
FROM DistanceMatrixFromGoogleMapsApi as dist
JOIN locations as orig
    ON dist.OriginLocationId = orig.id
JOIN locations as dest
    ON dist.DestinationLocationId = dest.id
WHERE dist.OriginLocationId in (30506,53097,30362,30505,30377,30378,30594,30379,30514,30518,30517,55055,30360,30515,30516,30616,30512,30511,30510,30513,30381,49129)
AND dist.DestinationLocationId in (53097,30362,30505,30377,30378,30594,30379,30514,30518,30517,55055,30360,30515,30516,30616,30512,30511,30510,30513,30381,49129,34690)
```